# Getting weird traffic from an unknown IP

Tags: security, https, ip, ddos

These past few weeks my site has been receiving unknown traffic from several IP's which turn out an AWS machine, for example, `52.44.93.197`. The requests seems replicate a real user request before hand. At first, we thought, there's a monitoring server that listens to pages that don't use https.

But even after we use https, we still get similar requests. Even if we ban the IP, a new one will show up and repeat the similar behavior.

Can anyone with similar experience share their thoughts?

Comment: How many requests? What endpoints do they hit? Do they try out random login/password combination? SQLI? What _do_ they request? The given information isn't enough to answer this.

Comment: basically all kinds of endpoints after an original user request. all of them are GET requests, no attempt of login bruteforce. Just that they repeat an original GET request to a page

Answer (score 1):

Use `Elasticsearch`, `Kibana`, `Beats` and `Logstash` to monitor your website. It would be better to block such ip's or servers trying to increase the traffic.